# A ="" doesn't empty a cell in VBA array?

Tags: arrays, vba

I've got an array with cells, some of which I need to clear on each iteration and rewrite on some other iteration. However if I clear the cell using ="" afterwords the addition won't work with an error 13 "type mismatch".

```
Sub test()

Dim array1(2, 2)
array1(1, 1) = 6
array1(1, 1) = ""
array1(1, 1) = array1(1, 1) + 1
Debug.Print (array1(1, 1))

End Sub
```

The strange thing is that if I use "" in if statement it works both with brand new array and array where cells were changed using =""

```
if array1(2, 2) = "" then
array1(2, 2)=array1(2, 2)+1
endif
```

So the question is, how to properly empty a specific cell in an array?

Comment: `If array1(2, 2) = "" Then array1(2, 2) = 1`. Alternately, you can use `array1(1, 1) = Empty`.

Comment: `array1(2, 2)=val(array1(2, 2))+1`

Comment: `Dim array1(2, 2)` => you define an array of Variant. `array1(1, 1) = 6` => Subtype of array1(1,1) become Variant/Long. `array1(1, 1) = ""` => Subtype of array1(1,1) become Variant/String. `array1(1, 1) = array1(1, 1) + 1` you are adding Variant/String and Long...

Comment: thanks that was helpful, and -empty was what i was really looking for